# How to merge more than two columns and export to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, append

I have three numpy arrays, all in shape of (10,1).
I want to merge all and export to csv.

For 2 arrays I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
L = np.append(x, y, axis=1)
pd.DataFrame(L).to_csv('test.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

but here `np.append()` does not work as I have more than two arrays.

Comment: Please share a sample of all input arrays with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.concatenate` instead and pass in a list of your numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arrays = [x, y, z]
concatenated = np.concatenate(arrays, axis=1)
```

In one line:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([x, y, z], axis=1)).to_csv('test.csv', header=False, index=False)
```